# Remove Gnome from 12.10

Tags: 12.10, gnome

In a previous version of Ubuntu, I had installed Gnome (classic) as well as Gnome Shell. Now, after upgrading to 12.10, I'm satisfied with Unity and would like to remove the Gnome packages that are no longer needed. However, I'm concerned that I'll break Unity...

How can I safely remove Gnome classic and Gnome Shell from my system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do it with

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
```

and for gnome-classic

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-session-fallback
```

this won't break unity.

Comment: Depending upon how you installed the Gnome Classic, you might also need to remove `gnome-panel`. Also, remember to purge unused dependencies after these commands with `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: @JorgeSuárezdeLis I agree with you .+1.

Comment: I've confirmed that this removes Gnome, Gnome Classic, and a whole pile of dependencies. Unity unaffected. Thanks!

Comment: @rcourtna you're welcome Friend.

Answer (score 0):

**The easy way**

Look for a "meta package" that was installed as the "desktop", and by uninstalling this, apt should remove all packages that comprise the meta package. (I still need to confirm this, but just read it in a few posts here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110057)

---

**The hard way**

I went after the GNOME Desktop Manager

```
sudo apt-get purge gdm
```

and then to cleanup the leftovers

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**NOTE:** autoremove removes unneeded files associated to most recent purge/remove, so it needs to be run each and every time.

These two commands may not remove everything though, so to look for remaining items, I did

```
dpkg-query -l *desktop*
dpkg-query -l *gnome*
```

and purged the remaining packages from these lists (also using autoremove aftwards).

To check your progress, after each purge/remove/uninstall, flip back to GUI login screen (ctl-alt-f7) and watch it be dismantled.